# apt-mirror always wants to download

Tags: linux, updates, apt-get, apt, mirroring

apt-mirror is always trying to download ~430MB (every day).

```
Downloading 4 dep11 files using 4 threads...
Begin time: Wed Jan 16 09:04:43 2019
[4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Wed Jan 16 09:04:43 2019

Processing indexes: [SSSPPPPPPPPPPPPP]

436.4 MiB will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 10 archive files using 10 threads...
Begin time: Wed Jan 16 09:04:48 2019
[10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]... [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]...[0]...
End time: Wed Jan 16 09:04:48 2019

0 bytes in 0 files and 0 directories can be freed.
Run /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh for this purpose.

Running the Post Mirror script ...
(/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh)


Post Mirror script has completed. See above output for any possible errors.
```

Updates should work, as clients without Internet access are successfully patched every few days.

Have already tried to clean apt-cache, but without change.

Excpeted result is 0MB to download, actual result every day ist ~430MB to download. It's important for me because I processa and evaluate the logs.

[Logfile](https://www.photo-album.at/image/9QBC)

Comment: Isn't that what apt-mirror is supposed to do, create a mirror of apt sources? If you don't want a mirror, and just want to do a regular update, why not remove/disable apt-mirror?

Comment: @Xen2050 thats correct and i need the mirror. but it never finishes and i dont know why. every execution ~430MB left

Comment: How much free space is there?

Comment: 150GB free space

Comment: having same issue...did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this script fixed my issue https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/113

Check the modified version of the script (scroll down)

**UPDATE** with details.

I used the script posted by rinnaz. Saved that as a *.sh file and ran it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# combined solutions for apt mirror from: https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/49,https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/102
# I had to create this file, in order to solve the issue of not downloading DEP-11 @2 files
# so all what I'm doing is running apt mirror manually, then downloading the other icon files every time
# Grep will grep the line starting with "set base_path"
# then we trim all extra white spaces
# then we cut the string by delimiter white space and take third value

dataFolder=$(grep -F "set base_path" /etc/apt/mirror.list | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f3)
echo "Base Folder path set in /etc/apt/mirror.list is: $dataFolder"
apt-mirror
echo 
echo -n "Do you want to Check MD5 Sum and Download Failed (auto Y in 5 seconds)? [Y/n]"
echo
read -t 5 answer
exit_status=$?
if [ $exit_status -ne 0 ] || [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ];then
    FAILEDPACKAGES=""
    echo "Reading and Checking MD5 checksum using file: $dataFolder/var/MD5"
    #cd $dataFolder/mirror
    rm -f FAILED_MD5.txt
    echo "Failed File will be stored in: $(PWD)/FAILED_MD5.txt"
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        #echo "Checking: $line"
        sum=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
        filename=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
        echo "$sum $dataFolder/mirror/$filename" | md5sum -c -
        RESULT=$?
        if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ];then
            echo "$dataFolder/mirror/$filename" >> FAILED_MD5.txt
            wget -O $dataFolder/mirror/$filename $filename
            echo "$sum $dataFolder/mirror/$filename" | md5sum -c -
            SUBRESULT=$?
            if [ $SUBRESULT -ne 0 ];then
                echo "Sorry failed checksum again for file: $dataFolder/mirror/$filename"
                $FAILEDPACKAGES+="$dataFolder/mirror/$filename      Failed again, sorry cannot help"
            fi
        fi
    done
```